# Can a cpu core run multiple applications concurrently on spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two questions about Apache spark.

1. I built a spark standalone cluster, each worker has 4 cores, does that mean I can only have 4 applications running concurrently on a worker at most?
2. I have a process that I want it to be running regularly, what would be the best practice? Call `spark-submit` in a cron job or just loop my code in the driver?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Regarding (2), will you be using another cluster manager ever, or are you only linking Spark jobs?

Comment: Hi, @Myles, I am still looking for a solution for our application, so I will try YARN or Mesos if standalone mode cannot meet our requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Learning Spark, Chapter 7 p. 132](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do):

> "When sharing a Spark cluster among multiple applications, you will
>   need to decide how to allocate resources between the executors. The
>   Standalone cluster manager has a basic scheduling policy that allows
>   capping the usage of each application so that multiple ones may run
>   concurrently. Apache Mesos supports more dynamic sharing while an
>   application is running, while YARN has a concept of queues that allows
>   you to cap usage for various sets of applications."

So, this should help you with 2. The authors also have a variety of points to help you decide which cluster manager to use on page 138-139. In general, Chapter 7 of this book is invaluable and I highly recommend the purchase (Databricks has a Promo Code).

Regarding question 1, you configure resource allocation by setting: (1) executor memory and (2) the maximum number of total cores. It sounds like you've already set the maximum number of cores, so consider executor memory. Each application gets one executor (and only as much memory as you allow). You can have multiple executors per core.

You can verify these settings for stand-alone mode by going to http://masternode:8080.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html) seems to provide an answer, that does not meet my intuition or expectations:

> The standalone cluster mode currently only supports a simple FIFO scheduler across applications. However, to allow multiple concurrent users, you can control the maximum number of resources each application will use. By default, it will acquire all cores in the cluster, which only makes sense if you just run one application at a time. You can cap the number of cores by setting spark.cores.max in your SparkConf

What I gather from this, is that indeed, a process will completely lock down a CPU core that has been assigned to it, until it is done running.
In your case, you could indeed assign 1 core to each process, but other processes will apparently be put in a queue, until cores free up.

Regarding your second question: I would avoid letting a single application run and loop forever, because that would prevent it from relinquishing control over the CPU core it was using. Kicking it off in a cron job fashion will prevent this type of CPU hogging.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I read the document too and that's why I am confusing about it, b/c it reads as if the standalone mode can only execute jobs in order(FIFO)